# Tiny_mce + comments in Django = problem

Tags: django, comments, tinymce

I written a small comments app.
Part of forms.py:

```
class TinyCommentForm(CommentSecurityForm):
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
```

Part of models.py:

```
class TinyComment(BaseCommentAbstractModel):
    comment = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
```

Part of template which using TinyCommentForm:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% get_comment_form for object as form %}        
    <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="POST">
        {{ form.comment }}
        {{ form.content_type }}
        {{ form.object_pk }}
        {{ form.timestamp }}
        {{ form.security_hash }}              
        <input type="submit" name="post" class="submit-post" value="Add" />
    </form>
{%endif%}
```

Here I can adding and saving comments, but only without tinymce editor and that is working fine.

If I add to my comment form in template field: `{{form.media}}` tinymce editor show up, but if I write something there, my POST form seems to be without content, saying that I need to write something to it.

Giving `{{form.media}}` to `<HEAD>` sector does not working even if I render through my view the TinyCommentForm as 'form' to this template.

So i tried to import JS more manually and I add to `<HEAD>` section(using Django 1.3):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

Then I check that the src link and it is correct.

So next I add second line there:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url tinymce-js "NAME" %}"></script>
```

Then I create `NAME/tinymce_textareas.js` with JS code and add containing this folder to TEMPLATE_DIRS. MY urls including tiny_mce urls. But still without results.

Does somebody could illumine me a little?

Answer (score 1):

**Got it working good. Answer:**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% get_comment_form for object as form %}        
    <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="POST">
        {{ form.media }} <!-- This is needed -->
        {{ form.comment }}
        {{ form.content_type }}
        {{ form.object_pk }}
        {{ form.timestamp }}
        {{ form.security_hash }}              
        <input type="submit" name="post" class="submit-post" value="Add" />
    </form>
{%endif%}
```

And any JS in  section was needless.
But the devil lives in my forms.py which should looks like this:

```
class TinyCommentForm(CommentSecurityForm):
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Texarea)
```

And now everythigng works properly.

**Edit:** The reason of why my comment form need to using `widget=forms.Texarea` is, i think, that my texareas.js has `mode : "textareas"`. If I am wrong please correct me.